# Long tablebase wins in tournament praxis

Tags: endgame, tablebases

I very much assume that KBB/KN endgames already occurred often enough in OTB play, and I also bet the B side always played on for a win (regardless whether this was after the computer proved it was a win, and regardless whether it also was a win even within 50 move rule). KRN/KNN and KRB/KNN are a different matter, though: the only reason to play out the inhuman win is the fact that your opponent is only human either.

Thus: Any pawnless material constellation with a long (around 50 moves at least) tablebase win "counts" for my question. (I.e. not BN or Q/R, although self-foot-shooting happened there too, nor QP/Q. But e.g. Q/two minors counts.) The *only* material one immediately thinks of here, but has no interest for me, is RB/R: "anyone" knows the opponent can be tortured for free, having to surviver another excruciating 50 moves. It's also rather common - I was on both sides myself.

Can you dig up some examples for various material distributions on the megabases? (Shouldn't be difficult, search-wise.) Did the stronger side play on? And actually score a win, which would be really remarkable (except the weaker side was also much weaker in rating) in the RN/NN and RB/NN cases? Please include the year of play.